# how do i turn on hardare virtualization on my pc?

Tags: motherboard, bios, virtualization

How do i update my bios ([G41C-S][1])? I have ASrock G41SC motherboard with a P4 2.8GHz processor.

```
    [System Summary]

Item            Value
OS Name         Microsoft Windows XP Professional
Version         5.1.2600 Service Pack 3, v.3244 Build 2600
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Type     X86-based PC
Processor       x86 Family 15 Model 3 Stepping 4 GenuineIntel ~2792 Mhz
BIOS Version/Date American Megatrends Inc. P1.40, 9/21/2010
SMBIOS Version  2.5 
Hardware Abstraction Layer Version = "5.1.2600.3244 (xpsp.071030-1537)"
```

Comment: First ensure your CPU supports the feature.

Answer (score 0):

If your information is correct (P4 @2.8GHz) you have some Prescott core CPU (511, 520 or 521), so don't bother with BIOS updating; your CPU doesn't support Visualization technology